# SonarScanner Displaying 'Analysis Success' But SonarQube Is Not Showing Code Report

Tags: sonarqube, sonarscanner

I am trying to use SonarScanner to scan a C language program and send it over to SonarQube but I am being shown "The main branch has no lines of code." while the SonarScanner says "Analysis Success" and "Execution Success".

OS VERSION : Windows 10

STEPS FOLLOWED:

1. I created a project manually and chose "Other (for JS, TS, Go, Python, PHP) as the build of the code instead of .NET, Maven or Gradle.
2. In the conf folder, I added the last 3 lines to the content of the Sonar-Scanner properties source file:

```
#Configure here general information about the environment, such as SonarQube server connection details for example

#No information about specific project should appear here

#----- Default SonarQube server

#sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000

#----- Default source code encoding

#sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000

sonar.projectKey=CarbonFootprintCalculator

sonar.sources=D:\New folder
```

3. I ran the following command in the same folder as my code (New Folder in D Drive) to send it to Localhost:9000 using SonarScanner:

```
sonar-scanner.bat -D"sonar.projectKey=CarbonFootprintCalculator" -D"sonar.sources=D:\New folder." -D"sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000" -D"sonar.token=sqp_5e9cdc0c9da90779005ed42275dfa52e2a2fc08c"
```

4. The output of the above command was as follow:

```
INFO: Scanner configuration file: C:\sonarscanner\sonar-scanner-4.8.0.2856\bin\..\conf\sonar-scanner.properties

INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE

INFO: SonarScanner 4.8.0.2856

INFO: Java 17.0.7 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)

INFO: Windows 10 10.0 amd64

INFO: User cache: C:\Users\Yash Anand\.sonar\cache

INFO: Analyzing on SonarQube server 10.0.0.68432

INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "windows-1252" (analysis is platform dependent)

INFO: Load global settings

INFO: Load global settings (done) | time=189ms

INFO: Server id: 147B411E-AYfbfneOwzIRF7Nr5PrQ

INFO: User cache: C:\Users\Yash Anand\.sonar\cache

INFO: Load/download plugins

INFO: Load plugins index

INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=109ms

INFO: Load/download plugins (done) | time=423ms

INFO: Process project properties

INFO: Process project properties (done) | time=37ms

INFO: Execute project builders

INFO: Execute project builders (done) | time=5ms

INFO: Project key: CarbonFootprintCalculator

INFO: Base dir: D:\New folder

INFO: Working dir: D:\New folder\.scannerwork

INFO: Load project settings for component key: 'CarbonFootprintCalculator'

INFO: Load project settings for component key: 'CarbonFootprintCalculator' (done) | time=47ms

WARN: SCM provider autodetection failed. Please use "sonar.scm.provider" to define SCM of your project, or disable the SCM Sensor in the project settings.

INFO: Load quality profiles

INFO: Load quality profiles (done) | time=139ms

INFO: Load active rules

INFO: Load active rules (done) | time=4544ms

INFO: Load analysis cache

INFO: Load analysis cache (404) | time=22ms

INFO: Load project repositories

INFO: Load project repositories (done) | time=73ms

INFO: Indexing files...

INFO: Project configuration:

INFO: 1 file indexed

INFO: ------------- Run sensors on module CarbonFootprintCalculator

INFO: Load metrics repository

INFO: Load metrics repository (done) | time=81ms

INFO: Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco]

INFO: 'sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths' is not defined. Using default locations: target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml,target/site/jacoco-it/jacoco.xml,build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml

INFO: No report imported, no coverage information will be imported by JaCoCo XML Report Importer

INFO: Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco] (done) | time=18ms

INFO: Sensor CSS Rules [javascript]

INFO: No CSS, PHP, HTML or VueJS files are found in the project. CSS analysis is skipped.

INFO: Sensor CSS Rules [javascript] (done) | time=5ms

INFO: Sensor C# Project Type Information [csharp]

INFO: Sensor C# Project Type Information [csharp] (done) | time=9ms

INFO: Sensor C# Analysis Log [csharp]

INFO: Sensor C# Analysis Log [csharp] (done) | time=54ms

INFO: Sensor C# Properties [csharp]

INFO: Sensor C# Properties [csharp] (done) | time=2ms

INFO: Sensor HTML [web]

INFO: Sensor HTML [web] (done) | time=11ms

INFO: Sensor TextAndSecretsSensor [text]

INFO: Sensor TextAndSecretsSensor [text] (done) | time=33ms

INFO: Sensor VB.NET Project Type Information [vbnet]

INFO: Sensor VB.NET Project Type Information [vbnet] (done) | time=5ms

INFO: Sensor VB.NET Analysis Log [vbnet]

INFO: Sensor VB.NET Analysis Log [vbnet] (done) | time=56ms

INFO: Sensor VB.NET Properties [vbnet]

INFO: Sensor VB.NET Properties [vbnet] (done) | time=3ms

INFO: Sensor IaC Docker Sensor [iac]

INFO: 0 source files to be analyzed

INFO: 0/0 source files have been analyzed

INFO: Sensor IaC Docker Sensor [iac] (done) | time=367ms

INFO: ------------- Run sensors on project

INFO: Sensor Analysis Warnings import [csharp]

INFO: Sensor Analysis Warnings import [csharp] (done) | time=6ms

INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor

INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (done) | time=20ms

INFO: SCM Publisher No SCM system was detected. You can use the 'sonar.scm.provider' property to explicitly specify it.

INFO: CPD Executor Calculating CPD for 0 files

INFO: CPD Executor CPD calculation finished (done) | time=0ms

INFO: Analysis report generated in 326ms, dir size=124.7 kB

INFO: Analysis report compressed in 242ms, zip size=14.8 kB

INFO: Analysis report uploaded in 104ms

INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can find the results at: http://localhost:9000/dashboard?id=CarbonFootprintCalculator

INFO: Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report

INFO: More about the report processing at http://localhost:9000/api/ce/task?id=AYfhim_X6pznqzcwOF0s

INFO: Analysis total time: 16.530 s

INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------

INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS

INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------

INFO: Total time: 20.808s

INFO: Final Memory: 16M/57M

INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Additionally, I would like to add that opening “INFO: More about the report processing at http://localhost:9000/api/ce/task?id=AYfhim_X6pznqzcwOF0s” from the above output would lead to the following message being shown:

```
{"task":{"id":"AYfhim_X6pznqzcwOF0s","type":"REPORT","componentId":"AYfhY8l46pznqzcwOF0c","componentKey":"CarbonFootprintCalculator","componentName":"CarbonFootprintCalculator","componentQualifier":"TRK","analysisId":"AYfhinbEwzRX02DmXAyy","status":"SUCCESS","submittedAt":"2023-05-03T17:45:58+0530","submitterLogin":"admin","startedAt":"2023-05-03T17:46:00+0530","executedAt":"2023-05-03T17:46:05+0530","executionTimeMs":4695,"hasScannerContext":true,"warningCount":2,"warnings":[]}}
```

I am attaching the screenshot of the SonarQube dashboard as well as the Solar-Scanner properties source file below. Kindly please help me fix this issue:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAKzi.jpg

I tried to ensure that the Sonar-Scanner properties source file in the conf folder had been edited properly by me. Additionally, I ensured there wasn't any internet connection related issue. I also made sure SonarQube was running throughout the process.

Comment: This indicates that your default branch hasn’t been analyzed yet. It could be that currently you are only analyzing non default branches. Also make sure that the default branch on Sonarqube is the same as on code repo.

Comment: Also, if no harm then delete the project in sonarqube and then try to analyse by always setting the `sonar.branch.name` analysis parameter. More details in here https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analyzing-source-code/branches/branch-analysis/

Comment: Hi Sourav. The actual problem was that the community version of SonarQube does not support C Language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason due to which I was unable to see find the code report was that SonarCube's community version does not support C language. In order to work with C Language, you will be needing to upgrade to SonarCube's enterprise or developer's edition.

You can learn more about the supported languages of various SonarCube editions by clicking the link provided below:

https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/latest/analyzing-source-code/languages/overview/

Answer (score 0):

To scan a C, C++, or Objective-C project, you need to use the [build-wrapper](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analyzing-source-code/languages/c-family/#using-build-wrapper). You can't scan a C/C++/Objective-C project directly. You have to run the build-wrapper (which wraps your clean build command) and then you run the sonar-scanner.

Questions to consider:

1. What kind of project are you scanning? Is your compiler supported?
2. What is your build clean command for this project of just one file?
3. Why did you set your Sonar analysis parameters in the sonar-scanner.properties file? You should set the 3 Sonar analysis parameters in the sonar-project.properties file, which sits in the root of the project instead of the sonar-scanner.properties file. It's better to put project-dependent parameters grouped with your project so that you can version-control it.

Examples:

```
// example for linux
build-wrapper-linux-x86-64 --out-dir build_wrapper_output_directory make clean all
// example for macOS
build-wrapper-macosx-x86 --out-dir build_wrapper_output_directory xcodebuild clean build
// example for Windows
build-wrapper-win-x86-64.exe --out-dir  build_wrapper_output_directory MSBuild.exe /t:Rebuild /nodeReuse:False
```

See more here: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analyzing-source-code/languages/c-family/

In the future, you should go to https://community.sonarsource.com and create a thread there for help. Sonar devs/managers operate in their own forum, not StackOverflow.